# Retrieve the ID of particular View?

Tags: android

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.card_scroll_item, null);
viewFlipper.addView(view);
Button creditbtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.credit_button);
creditbtn.setBackgroundResource(carddraw[i]);
TextView txtname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.credit_type);
txtname.setText("Visa");
TextView txtnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.credit_number);
txtnumber.setText(creditnum[i]);
txtnumber.setTypeface(tf);`
```

I had used this code how to get on click event on each button

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set onClick listener for your button, something like this

```
creditbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Do your actions here             
        }
    });
```

Second you need to research first, then ask questions :)

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Implement the onClickListener interface in your activity class.

2. set creditbtn.setOnclickListener(this);

3. 

@Override
public void onClick(View view){

int id = view.getId();

switch(id){

case R.id.credit_type:

// do your stuff

break;

}

}
```

Hope this will help